# Incremental Compilation in Eclipse. ASTNode-s and SVN versioning

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree

I am building up some statistics after analyzing the source code in eclipse. But the overall process is too slow because i rebuild my model every time from scratch after each compilation.
**I am looking for a way to get only the changed parts of the code (as ASTNodes) and to rebuild just that part of my model.** I suppose that even the changed compilation units and not the exact code elements would be enough after the user compiles and still would be a nice optimization.

I am sure eclipse is capable of knowing what code elements are changed (and even to know their semantics), because when I use the subclipse plugin my changes are ordered by a code element (an import, a method, a variable declaration, etc). Well.. at least that plugin is capable of knowing that info.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse builder infrastructure is created for exactly this reason. For a start I suggest the [following article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Builders/builders.html) and [FAQ entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_an_Eclipse_builder%3F).